# How to find out more about the colour theory design of warning signs and labels?

Tags: color-theory, resource-recommendations

For a project, I have found that I wish to learn about the color theory of warning signs and labels, specifically those that use colors across a spectrum that indicate an increasing intensity or different expected approach of some kind such as the [DEFCON alert states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFCON) and the ["safety square"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NFPA_704).

However, I have found myself in the bit of the familiar issue of wanting to know more on a topic but not knowing the proper search terms to use to find out more on that topic. Not really knowing what else to do, I've come here.

So for that matter, I am asking: **what kind of resources can I use to find out more about the color theory of warning signs, labels, alert states, etc.?**

Comment: I don't have a specific resource to point to at this moment but I expect you will find some overlap with "color blindness" and "accessibility"

Comment: Blue and green may be a bit problematic as there are languages that dont differentiate between them. Most notably japanese although they have implemented this by now. This is also why the streetlights in japan have bluegreen lights. Also you might want to look what color science tells you about colors (color theory is not hard science color science is). Also then there is the fact that most colorblinds can not see red as effectively as the rest of population.